# why jquery not working in IE8 , but in chrome/firefox

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a problem with my jQuery code in IE 8.
I have a script that constructs some UI dynamically with div on load.
This works fine in chrome and firefox, but in IE it does not load.
It does not log anything when it comes to second line below.

```
AV.console.debug("start customer UI");
e = $("<div></div>").addClass("av-webassist-main").hide();
AV.console.debug("customerUI added main container");
```

It logs the first debug in console and nothing after that. The page stays blank.
If I try to run the second line in console,

```
e = $("<div></div>").addClass("av-webassist-main").hide();
```

it throws error **'null' is null or not an object**
I am clueless how to debug this. I am using jquery-1.9.1.js.

Comment: what does `AV.console.debug($.fn.jquery);` give you?

Comment: I think it breaks after I put above debug line. No error in console though. Then I ran $.fn.jquery in console script and it says => '$.fn.jquery' is null or not an object

Comment: what does `$.prototype` give you when you log it? http://pastebin.com

Comment: after $, it shows log  Added $ function() {
    var elements = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      var element = arguments[i];
      if (typeof element == 'string') {
        element = document.getElementById(element);
      }
      if (arguments.length == 1) {
        return element;
      }
      elements.push(element);
    }
    return elements;
  }

Comment: It appears as though you have something overriding `$`. use `jQuery` instead, or remove whatever is overriding `$`

Comment: @Kevin- after debug $ it prints a method                            and after $.prototype => $ [object Object]

Answer (score 4):

Remove or comment out your `console.debug` lines. IE chokes on them unless the console is open.

Comment: hmm.... you know he's using `AV.console.debug` and not `window.console.debug`, right? what is AV?

Comment: It is a custom object created. And the logging works fine for all previous debug. It only stuck when I get to the line mentioned above.

Comment: Might help to post your custom debugging code. And are you saying that when you remove the debug code it still has an error?

Answer (score 0):

Is jQuery loaded? Try this:

```
if (jQuery) {  
    alert('jQuery is loaded');
} else {
    alert('jQuery is not loaded');
}
```

What if you create the DIV in another way? Like

```
$(document.createElement('div'))
```

Does that change anything?

Comment: The OP did say that the code works in Chrome and Firefox so I assume jQuery is loaded and this is IE-centric.

Comment: Might be a timing issue... I've seen stranger things